# Faraday Cage with respect to Maxwell's Equations

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I could really use your help in understanding how a Faraday cage and Maxwell's Equations come together.

From my understanding:
For the electrostatic case, the Faraday cage cancels out an incoming Electric Field by rearrangement of the charges relating this case to Guass' Law.

For magnetostatics case, the static magnetic field will fully penetrate the Faraday cage as there are no magnetic dipoles relating this case to Guass' Law for Magnetism.

For the case with a changing Magnetic Field, this dynamic field results in a rotational induced EMF which in turn leads to an induced current that produces a magnetic field which opposes the initial external magnetic field resulting in no net magnetic field inside the Faraday cage. This relates to Faraday's Law of Induction.

The case with a changing Electric Field for some reason is confusing to me how it relates to Maxwell-Amperes Law.

The changing Electric field results in a rotational curling Magnetic Field that would circulate around the Faraday Cage.

How does this eventually lead to the charge redistributing giving an Electric Field that cancels out the incoming Electric Field?

Is it that the induced curling Magnetic Field induced a current which means the charges move, leading to a potential gradient that gives the cancelling Electric Field?

Maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way, but I'd really appreciate an explanation of the Faraday Cage as it applies to Maxwell's Equations.